# Skip reading characters from a data file C++

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I have a data file (A.dat) with following format:

```
Theta = 0.0000        Phi = 0.00000
Theta = 1.0000        Phi = 90.0000
Theta = 2.0000        Phi = 180.0000
Theta = 3.0000        Phi = 360.0000
```

I want to read the values (only) of theta and phi and store them in a data file (B.dat) like this:

```
0.0000        0.00000
1.0000        90.0000
2.0000        180.0000
3.0000        360.0000
```

I tried this :

```
    int main()
    {

      double C[4][2];

      ifstream fR;
      fR.open("A.dat");
      if (fR.is_open())
        {
          for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            fR >> C[i][0] >> C[i][1];  
        }
      else cout << "Unable to open file to read" << endl;
      fR.close();

      ofstream fW;
      fW.open("B.dat");

      for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        fW << C[i][0] << '\t' << C[i][1] << endl;

      fW.close();
    }
```

I get this in B.dat:

```
0       6.95272e-310
6.95272e-310    6.93208e-310
1.52888e-314    2.07341e-317
2.07271e-317    6.95272e-310
```

How do I skip reading characters and other things and save only the digits?

Comment: Why not just read lines and then parse them?

Comment: Why not using tools like `sed` to do that ?

Comment: I agree with David, [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) would help immensely, and so might using [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to filter. I recommend wrapping this in to some method, perhaps in your own namespace. A lot of stuff to have in `int main()`.

Comment: `string str;`...`fR >> str >> str >> C[i][0] >> str >> str>> C[i][1];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to skip past unwanted data because it allows you to read up to (and past) a specific character (in this case the '='):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

// pretend file stream
std::istringstream data(R"(
Theta = 0.0000        Phi = 0.00000
Theta = 1.0000        Phi = 90.0000
Theta = 2.0000        Phi = 180.0000
Theta = 3.0000        Phi = 360.0000
)");

int main()
{

    double theta;
    double phi;
    std::string skip; // used to read past unwanted text

    // set printing format to 4 decimal places
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4);

    while( std::getline(data, skip, '=')
        && data >> theta
        && std::getline(data, skip, '=')
        && data >> phi
    )
    {
        std::cout << '{' << theta << ", " << phi << '}' << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{0.0000, 0.0000}
{1.0000, 90.0000}
{2.0000, 180.0000}
{3.0000, 360.0000}
```

**NOTE:**

I put the reading statements inside the `while()` condition. This works because reading from a *stream* returns the *stream* object and when put into an `if()` or a `while()` condition it returns `true` if the read was successful or `false` if the read failed.

So the loop terminates when you run out of data.

Answer (score 2):

Read line by line your file and remove part you don't want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream in;
    std::ofstream out;

    in.open("A.dat");
    out.open("B.dat");

    if(in.is_open() && out.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(in, line))
        {
            line.erase(line.find("Theta"), std::strlen("Theta = "));
            line.erase(line.find("Phi"),   std::strlen("Phi = "));
            out << line << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With this method, you don't have to manage formatting of `double` when you write it to output file: it will be same as input file.

Comment: This 'erase' feature is new to me, it looks very helpful. Thank you.