# Ignore the "#" symbol when reading the file C++

Tags: c++

I have a file with the format below. I want to read the file in and print it out. But when I do read in and print, it will be some garbage. I think it is because the # symbol starts at the line. So, what is the right way to read in the whole file while ignoring the "#" line

```
int main(){
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("city_list.txt");
    string name;
    int zone;
    int rank;

    static std::string const symbols = "#";
    while (true){
     inFile >> zone >> name >> rank;
     cout << zone << " " << name<< " " << rank << endl
    }


}
```

Input File (city_list.txt)

```
# AFRICA Zone 1
1 Cairo_EG  30
1 Johannesburg_SA  -26
1 Lagos_NG  6

# ASIA Zone 2
2 Beijing_CN 3
#2 Hong_Kong_CN  2
```

Comment: I think your problem is the differing amount of whitespace and different format of the data. On the 1st line you have 3 strings to read before a number. On the second line it starts with a number then a string then a number. You probably want to read the whole line using std::getline() into a std::string and parse that.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want to print the file exactly as is, or do you want to ignore the '#'s?

Comment: @lnogueir I want to print lines without the "#" symbol

Comment: You probably want to use getline()

Comment: @drescherjm I mean the line start with the "#" symbol doesn't need to be read.

Comment: You would still read the file a line at a time using std::getline() but then look at the string that was read. if line[0] == '#' don't cout it.

Comment: @drescherjm what if I want to store the value from the file into those variables ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39346853/14480038 is this answer your question?

Comment: You can parse the line with std::istringstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("city_list.txt");
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(inFile, line)) {
        std::string cleanLine = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if(line[i] != '#') {
                    cleanLine += line[i];
            }
        }
        std::cout << cleanLine << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check/try this code on https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/IgnoreCommentsInFile#main.cpp

**My solution - main.cpp**
Check blank spaces at beginning of the line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

class Strings
{
public:

    static std::string TrimStart(const std::string& data)
    {
        std::string s = data;
        s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char ch) {
            return !std::isspace(ch);
        }));
        return s;
    }

    static std::string TrimEnd(const std::string& data)
    {
        std::string s = data;
        s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), [](unsigned char ch) {
            return !std::isspace(ch);
        }).base(),
            s.end());
        return s;
    }

    static std::string Trim(const std::string& data)
    {
        return TrimEnd(TrimStart(data));
    }
};

void CreateFile()
{
    std::string filename = "city_list.txt";
    std::string content = u8R"(# AFRICA Zone 1
1 Cairo_EG  30
1 Johannesburg_SA  -26
1 Lagos_NG  6



# ASIA Zone 2
    # a comment
2 Beijing_CN 3
#2 Hong_Kong_CN  2
)";
    
    std::ofstream outfile(filename);
    outfile << content;
    outfile.close();   
}



void ReadPrintFile()
{
    std::string filename = "city_list.txt";
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        line = Strings::Trim(line);
        if (line[0] != '#' && line.size()>0)
        {
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
    infile.close();
}

int main()
{ 
    CreateFile();
    ReadPrintFile();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1 Cairo_EG  30
1 Johannesburg_SA  -26
1 Lagos_NG  6
2 Beijing_CN 3
```

[image: windows]
[image: Linux]